# How Function.prototype.call.bind works in this code

Tags: javascript

I really could use an explanation from anybody.

Seriously confused about this code. Especially line 2.

Code source is https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

```
var unboundSlice = Array.prototype.slice;
var slice = Function.prototype.call.bind(unboundSlice);

function list() {
  return slice(arguments);
}

var list1 = list(1, 2, 3); // [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: It hard-wires (so to speak) the `.call` part of `Array.prototype.slice.call`, turning a method of an array instance into a function that instead takes an array as an argument.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`var slice = Function.prototype.call.bind(unboundSlice);`

Pass `unboundSlice` as context (`this` operator) that function `call` will execute.
So when execute:
`list(1,2,3)` <=>

`slice([1,2,3])` <=>

excecute `call` with context `unboundSlice` and parameter `arguments`: `unboundSlice.call(arguments)` <=>

execute `unboundSlice` function with context `arguments (array [1,2,3])`:`[1,2,3].unboundSlice()` <=>

execute: `[1,2,3].slice()` <=>

`[1, 2, 3]`

Comment: Thank you so much.